# VBA Disable alert/dialog box when ... (Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not work)

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Hi, solution to my problem with this warning dialog box is not Application.DisplayAlerts = False/true
and can not find correct way to disable this alert. Can you help me please
(all options are set correctly?  i tried also enabled macros)

[image]

Comment: show us please how you call that macro. Add an error handler to the calling procedure.

Comment: Change the *Macro Settings* to *Enable all macros* and you won't have that message!

Comment: i tried also this option, but still does not work...still same dialog box

Comment: Do you actually have a macro by that name in that workbook?

Answer (score 0):

As @R3uK said, you need to chose *Enable all macros* instead of *Disable all macros with notification* which throws you that notification. And when you have macros disabled then `application.DisplayAlerts = false` isnt executed and then not working.